# Any way to export recorded testsuite (Not testcase) from HTML to C# in Selenium

Tags: selenium

Currently Selenium IDE not supporting for Export Test suite as C# from HTML. Its time consuming by converting the test cases one by one manually. any body has any idea to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there isn't a mechanism to export test suites from IDE. No one has written one. I think that you will have to do each test and then create a Suite